# How to use control operator after a heredoc in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script to create MySQL database automatically. The bash script is like the following (please ignore those variable $db_name, $db_pwd...):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mysql -u root << EOF
    CREATE DATABASE $db_name;
    CREATE USER $db_user IDENTIFIED BY $db_pwd;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $db_name.* TO $db_user;
    quit
EOF
printf "Done"
```

I want the database creation to be completed successfully and the print command runs afterwards. But I can not put the && after EOF, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mysql -u root << EOF
    CREATE DATABASE $db_name;
    CREATE USER $db_user IDENTIFIED BY $db_pwd;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $db_name.* TO $db_user;
    quit
EOF &&
printf "Done"
```

It will show the error like:

```
invalid command name "EOF"
    while executing
"EOF &&"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Where are you using `&&` in the code posted? Did you post the full code under problem

Comment: @Inian: Yes, I updated the question. I put && right after EOF close tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy workaround is to exit if mysql fails.

```
sudo mysql -u root << EOF || exit
    CREATE DATABASE $db_name;
    CREATE USER $db_user IDENTIFIED BY $db_pwd;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $db_name.* TO $db_user;
EOF
echo "Done"
```

Or you could add `set -e` to cause any failed command to immediately exit the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

sudo mysql -u root << EOF
    CREATE DATABASE $db_name;
    CREATE USER $db_user IDENTIFIED BY $db_pwd;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $db_name.* TO $db_user;
EOF
echo "Done"
```

Comment: `&& printf 'Done\n'` can also just be used in place of `|| exit`.

Answer (score 3):

The parsing is strange, but can be used to. Newlines (and comments) after `|` `&&` `||` are ignored. So you just write on the end of the line with the command, but after `<< EOF`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mysql -u root << EOF &&
    CREATE DATABASE $db_name;
    CREATE USER $db_user IDENTIFIED BY $db_pwd;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $db_name.* TO $db_user;
    quit
EOF
printf "Done"
```

Example:

```
grep -q bla << EOF &&
bla bla
EOF
# this comment is ignored

# lines with spaces, tabs and newlines and comments only are ignored
# until the first line with something is encountered
# the following will execute only if grep returns zero status
# it can be misleading

# Because you can write a LOT here, but bash stil just sees `grep && printf`
printf "grep matched successfully"
```

Example at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/64dhOa).

Comment: Just keep in mind that the here document doesn't start until the line *following* the command. `<<EOF` isn't *part* of the here document, it just says that one terminated by `EOF` will follow.

Answer (score 0):

put sudo into round brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash
(sudo mysql -u root << EOF
   ...
EOF
) && [next command]
```

Comment: That introduces a new shell for no real reason. Curly braces would be better if you really want the `&& ...` to follow the hear document.